# customized UIAlert for cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

please help me in making customized alert for cocos2d so that It looks like exactly UIAlertview. At the time of showing customised alert view control should remain fully on customised alertview. How can I ensure that?

thanks  in advance.

Comment: If you want it to look exactly like UIAlertView, why don't you use UIAlertView?

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer:

I can't help you much with the look of the alert view. However, to stop the user interacting in the background, you can put your alert view on a (slightly grayed) layer which responds to touches and swallows them so that they aren't passed through to the scene underneath.

Please consider sharing your alert view code when you've finished it as this would be quite useful to me.